# Customize treeview items in package explorer in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ide, spring-tool-suite

[image]

Spring Tool Suite 4.4.2, KDE Plasma 5.3. 
Is it possible to reduce spaces between items in this treeview in package explorer? (I'm not talking about changing font size. I already did it)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it has to do anything with STS... This is probably a problem with SWT on KDE Plasma 5.3. If you don't see he spacing between tree items the same elsewhere in your UI outside of Eclipse I'd raise an issue against Eclipse SWT project.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to change the spacing by modifying the CSS. The way I understand it, since Eclipse 4, the IDE is fully 'themeable' via CSS. So in principle it should be possible to control the spacing.

As I haven't tried it myself, I have no idea if it will work for you though. The best I can give you is a pointer to some info about the CSS stuff:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS